# I have migrated my Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4 but Display Actual Price in Magneto 2 backend is not showing?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

I have migrated my Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4 but  Display Actual Price in Magneto 2 backend is not showing ?

[image]

check in ss here is no option for Display Actual Price.

Any one suggest me why this is not showing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable that feature under

> STORES -> Settings -> Configuration -> SALES -> Sales -> Minimum Advertised Price

and set

> Enable MAP to **Yes**

first in order to have Advertised and Actual Price settings available in Advanced Pricing